# How to get rid of page margin created by translating divs

Tags: html, css

I have three `divs` on my webpage that have been `translated` up about `20px` each so the background images need to overlap. But now, because I have used the `transform: translate;` function with `CSS`, this has created a space of `60px` at the bottom of the webpage. I am looking for a way to get rid of this problem.

Currently in my `CSS` I have already got;

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And have tried things such as `margin-bottom: -60px;` and `padding-bottom: -60px`. I have also tried resizing the `height` of some of the `divs`. Unfortunately these have not worked for me. This is not a default browser border or anything. It is a space created from translating `divs` up. I have looked through various questions about this on this website but I have not been successful in my search.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: would you share your code?

Comment: create codepen or something for us.

Comment: `margin-bottom: -60px` should work, while `padding` may not be negative (for obvious reasons)

Comment: try `*{margin:0px auto;}`

Comment: Translation doesn't *actually* move the divs...it just appears to...but without your code we can't help much further.